# CodeMirror 6, how to get editor selection event

Tags: codemirror-6

I want to highlight the codemirror6 select text, this is the hightlight function look like:

```
const hightlightSelection = (selectedText: string, editorView: EditorView) => {
    let cursor = new SearchCursor(editorView.state.doc, selectedText);
    const highlight_effect = StateEffect.define<Range<Decoration>[]>();
    cursor.next();
    const highlight_decoration = Decoration.mark({
        attributes: { style: "background-color: yellow" }
    });
    if (editorView) {
        editorView.dispatch({
            effects: highlight_effect.of([highlight_decoration.range(1, 4)])
        });  
    }
}
```

but how to capture the selection event in codemirror6? I have tried like this:

```
    if(editorView){
        editorView.dom.addEventListener("selectionchange", () => {
            debugger
            const selection = editorView.state.selection;
            // handle selection change
            console.log("selection text:" + selection);
          });
    }
```